# function with a variable ksh like in js

Tags: unix, ksh

in java script, one can write a function as

```
function divideByThree(number) {
    return number / 3;
};

console.log(divideByThree(10));
```

which gives the output of 3.33333....

how do I write the same thing in ksh?

I tried this:

```
divideByThree(number) {
    number / 3;
};

echo divideByThree(10);
```

but got this:

```
-ksh: .: syntax error: `(' unexpected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
divideByThree() {
    echo $(( $1 / 3.0 ))
}

divideByThree 10
echo $(divideByThree 10)
result=$(divideByThree 10)
echo $result
```

Bash does not support floating point arithmetic; Korn shell does.  If you omit the `.0` from `3.0`, the division is integer division and the result is therefore 3.  The `return` statement returns a status value; you generally use `echo` to get a value for capture in a variable, etc.